# How to reach css and image files from the html page loaded by javafx.scene.web.WebEngine#loadContent?

Tags: java, webview, javafx-2

I have a String HTML content which is loaded into `webEngine` by `loadContent()` method. I have also some css and image files used in this page. Although I put these file into the same package of java class, the loaded page cannot find them. Looked for API docs and web, but could not find any appropiate similar solutions. How I load these files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set your local paths in html string for `loadContent` next way:

```
view.getEngine().loadContent(
"<img src='" + getClass().getResource("1.jpg") + "' />");
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this for a BufferedImage in memory?

Comment: @alistair you can use ImageIO class ,it has a method to read Buffered Images.

Answer (score 11):

You can place your string html content in a file in the same package as the Java class and use the `engine.load(String url)` method instead:

```
engine.load(getClass().getResource("mypage.html").toExternalForm());
```

When you do this, all relative links in the html page will resolve to resources (e.g. css and image files) in your Java package.

Beware that if you are loading a resource that is located in a jar file, that the `jar:` protocol does not understand relative links with parent specifiers.  E.g., `<img src="../images/image.png"/>` will not work, but `<img src="/images/image.png"/>` or `<img src="images/image.png"/>` will as long (as you put the image in the appropriate location in the jar file).  The `file:` protocol does not have such restrictions and `..` relative links will work fine when the resources are loaded using it.

If the html string is dynamically generated by your java code rather than static, then Sergey's solution is probably best.

Answer (score 5):

I just found out that using the `<base>` tag in the HTML also does the trick:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The slash at the end of the href is important!</title>
        <base href="file:///absolute/path/to/your/docroot/" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="image.png"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you load the above code via `engine.loadContent(String)` then `image.png` will be loaded from `/absolute/path/to/your/docroot/image.png`.

This method is easier if you need to load multiple resources since you only have to specify the absolute path at a single place.

This has been tested with `WebView` of Java 8u25.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<link href="file:css\default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```