# Can not display local image file as WebEngine image src attribute

Tags: webview, javafx-2

I'm trying to set the src of an img tag I have dynamically. The following piece of code works when running from eclipse but not after exporting it as a running jar file:

```
doc.getElementById("user-thumb").setAttribute("src", selectedVcard.getThumb().getFilePath());
```

The element got by the "user-thumb" id is an image. The thumb object returned is a simple custom ImageView I've extended to hold more information and is initialized using:

```
public Thumb(String url) {
    super(url);
    this.setFilePath(url);
    getStyleClass().add("thumb");
}
```

the method getFilePath() is returning a path from a temporary file starting with:

```
file:/
```

But I've already tried to change it to

```
file://
```

and even:

```
file:///
```

and got no success. I have googled and searched here but every answer points to start with file://. Is there something wrong with my code or is it javafx 2? By the way, I'm using javafx 2.2 GA and the jre 1.7.0.6 from oracle. Cheers

Comment: is this image located inside jar?

Comment: No, it's a file passed via socket and stored as a temporary file in the user (client) machine. Note please that in my Thumb (ImageView) the image is displayed perfectly, the WebView will even show the image if I use the ContextMenuItem Show Image in another window, it just won't display it. It's starting to seem like a bug

Comment: I guess you are running as a click to run jar not webstart or an applet? (otherwise security restrictions could cause this behaviour).  I also guess that the image cannot be loaded from a relative path to the source document? (otherwise you may be able to workaround this by using the relative path).

Comment: I tried running as a click first and then realized it could generate this security restriction, so I'm using the console even under Windows 7.This is a cross-platform application where the server is under a Unix environment and the client is working on Linux, MacOsX and Windows. I can't use relative path since it's a temporary file, which means it has it's path provided by the system.

Comment: There is better and easier solution at [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923801/how-to-reach-css-and-image-files-from-the-html-page-loaded-by-javafx-scene-web-w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Data URI for the images](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/)

Something like ...

```
String imageMimeType = "image/jpeg"; // Replace this for the correct mime of the image
String dataURI = "data:" + imageMimeType + ";base64," + 
     javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageByteArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and for your answer! I'll try tomorrow since I'm not at work right now!

Comment: @Bruno Vieira - just in case it's not obvious, you'd need to change the imageMimeType string based on the actual type of image, gif, jpeg, png etc.

Comment: It did the trick!!! Thank you very much for the contribution! It was exactly what I needed!