# how to add a local img with file://... in javafx webkit

Tags: java, html, javafx, webkit

I want to show a picture in javafx webview local html. here is my code, But I found the picture can not be shown.The image url is "file:/D:/a.jpg".

[image]

```
//Main WebViewBrowser.java

public class WebViewBrowser extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        WebView browser = new WebView();
        browser.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
        WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        String url = this.getClass().getResource("t.html").toExternalForm();
        System.out.println(url);
        //out put is "jar:file:/D:/data/netbeans/WebViewBrowser1/dist/run690102893/WebViewBrowser.jar!/webviewbrowser/t.html"
        Scene scene = new Scene(browser);
        webEngine.load(url);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


//t.html
//.............
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <img src="a.jpg" alt="aaa"/>  <!-- the relative path works -->
    <img src="file:/D:/a.jpg" alt="aaa"/>  <!-- the absolute path dos not work.why ?-->
</body>
 </html>
```

I just want to know how i can load the image which url is like 'file:/D:/a.jpg'.
Thak you very much.

Comment: It works for me. Have you tried opening t.html from a browser? Do you see the image twice?

Comment: yes, i can see both of the two image when i open t.html in my browser. but the absolute path in javafx dong not work.

Comment: I am sorry, i test again, it works. My problem is happened when t.html is in a jar, just like t.html has "jar:file:/D:/application.jar!/com/example/t.html"   , then the first image is in the jar too. The second image is still "file:/D:/a.jpg", then this problem happens.

Comment: If you still have problems, please edit your question and give more details of your configuration.

Comment: I had update the problem description, the full test code is there. thank you very very much.

Comment: I upload my project [here](http://moneypublic.qiniudn.com/WebViewBrowser1.7z), you can download it and have a test with netbeans. Don not froget copy a.jpg to D:/a.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new description of your problem, I can reproduce it too: it seems `WebView` can't access to local files if the web page is loaded from a jar file.

After searching for a while, I've just found this bug report on JIRA (you need to be registered to access to it):

- [RT-39031](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-39031) [WebView] local images not loaded when web page is loaded from jar file

As it is pointed out in the report, if you right-click over the alt description, you can load the image on a new window, what means it's not a problem of security restrictions (sandbox).

For the moment there's no easy solution. One that is proposed also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288697/can-not-display-local-image-file-as-webengine-image-src-attribute) is encoding the image as a base64 string:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,(...)" />

public String pathToBase64(String path) throws IOException {
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
}
```

Other solution is using `webEngine.loadContent()`. There's already an example [here](https://github.com/dahuapp/dahu/blob/760f5a69111b480e963316c623717dd416a4f86c/editor/src/main/java/io/dahuapp/editor/app/DahuApp.java) that may work.

**EDIT**

As the OP points out, there's another workaround to deal with local images loading, based on the use of a custom URL protocol. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522343/custom-javafx-webview-protocol-handler) there's already a working solution. For the image loading this is a possible implementation:

```
private void loadImage() throws IOException {
    String imgPath = getURL().toExternalForm();
    String ext = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
    imgPath = imgPath.startsWith(PROTOCOL+"://") ? 
                 imgPath.substring((PROTOCOL+"://").length()) :
                 imgPath.substring((PROTOCOL+":").length());

    try{
        BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(new File(imgPath));
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(read, ext, os);
        data=os.toByteArray();
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("IO exception: "+ioe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are a help Warm-hearted person， much thanks。 I have solution this by create my custom url protocol named "mem", like "mem://xxx.jpg" and It works. I hope oracle can fix it in before too long. Thank you again.

Comment: That's a really hacky workaround! I've checked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522343/custom-javafx-webview-protocol-handler) and made it work too, so I'll add it to the answer as another possible solution.