# Set a local image in JavaFX HTMLeditor

Tags: image, javafx, html-editor

I'm looking for a way to use JavaFX HTMLEditor's setHtmlText to add a *local* image.  I can add a remote image no problem:

```
HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();  
    editor.setHtmlText("<img src=\"http://someaddress.com\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\" >");
```

but can't do this for a local image

```
HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();  
    editor.setHtmlText("<img src=\"categoryButton.fw.png\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\" >");
```

This button is on the same level as the java source.  So why won't this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to get the location of the local image resource.

```
editor.setHtmlText(
  "<img src=\"" + 
     getClass().getResource("categoryButton.fw.png") + 
  "\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\" >"
);
```

It works the same way as loading content into [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) as in:

[How to reach css and image files from the html page loaded by javafx.scene.web.WebEngine#loadContent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923801/how-to-reach-css-and-image-files-from-the-html-page-loaded-by-javafx-scene-web-w)

---

Here is an screenshot:

[image: editorwithimage]

And an executable sample:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HTMLEditorWithImage extends Application {
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();
    editor.setHtmlText(
      "<img src=\"" + 
         getClass().getResource("Blue-Fish-icon.png") + 
      "\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\" >"
    );
    stage.setScene(new Scene(editor));
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

---

> I was just curious if this was the only way of getting an image into a some sort of text area?

1. With JavaFX 2, you can embed images mixed with text into a [FlowPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html) as described in [Javafx Text multi-word colorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081892/javafx-text-multi-word-colorization).
2. Java 8 adds a [TextFlow](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/Rich+Text+API+Samples) component which allows you to embed an image into a text region.

Both of the above techniques are for data display only. Neither allow for editing of the multi-styled text with images and other nodes inserted in it.  For now, the only controls provided by the JavaFX platform for this functionality are the [HTMLEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) or a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) with [contenteditable true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685395/webview-with-contenteditable-cannot-be-focused-programmatically) or an embedded [3rd party editor written in JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1463485).

There have been some 3rd party efforts to [create styled text editors using native JavaFX](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2013/02/20/from-styledtextviewer-to-a-styledtexteditor-with-javafx8/) constructs that don't rely on WebView or HTMLEditor, but as of today I don't think any are ready for widespread use.

Comment: btw I was also curious if this was the only way of getting an image into a some sort of text area?

Comment: Updated answer based on additional question - you may want to try a `WebView` with `contenteditable` set to true.

Answer (score 2):

Sample Code: Append file:\\ in the image tag to refer a local file.

```
ScreenCapture x = new ScreenCapture();
String imagePath = x.captureScreen(scCaptureCount+++"", "C:\\work\\temp");
String text = editor.getHtmlText();
editor.setHtmlText(text+"&lt;img src='file:\\\\"+imagePath+"' >" );
```

Answer (score 0):

This code insert image before the last end paragraph tag or end body tag.

```
String imgUrl = "http://..../image.png";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(htmlEditor.getHtmlText());
int pos = sb.lastIndexOf("</p>") > -1 ? sb.lastIndexOf("</p>") : sb.lastIndexOf("</body>");
sb.insert(pos, "<span><img src='" + imgUrl + "'></span>");
htmlEditor.setHtmlText(sb.toString());
```