# JavaFX WebView does not load upper folder script in jar

Tags: javascript, java, html, javafx, webview

Im trying to create code editor based on JavaFX WebView. I'm loading jquery to my .html file loaded by WebView like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Code editor</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        Loading...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, this file is loaded to WebView, but jquery is not loaded! script.js loaded but jquery-3.1.1.js is not! I'm suggesting the problem lying somewhere in file system. My files is stored as jar-file resources, so my index.html path is like:

```
jar:file:/D:/Pe3oHaHc/YandexDisk/Projects/Mira/Mira/build/libs/Mira-0.0.1.jar!/windows/html/editor/scripts.js
```

I get it by this code in my scripts.js:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
alert(scripts[1].src);
```

So, scripts.js loaded, but jquery-3.1.1.js is not cause it is in upper folder! And i cannot use $ in scripts.js.

But if i put my jquery-3.1.1.js in the same folder as a index.html it loaded well. I guess its because the strange path inside jar file. Can you help me? I'm realy don't want to place jquery file into same folder to index.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar protocol does not allow for `..` relative location specifiers.

A request to load a relative url from a resource loaded from a jar will use the same protocol as was used to load the original resource.  In this case, because the original resource is loaded from a jar, the `jar:` protocol is used.  You can find the definition of the jar protocol in the [JarURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) class documentation.

You could use a different protocol to load the resources, e.g. `http:` or `file:`, in which case `..` will work as those protocols understand `..`.  To do so, you would need to extract the relevant resources from the jar file and host them on a web server or [local file system](https://github.com/osiam/osiam/blob/master/src/main/java/org/osiam/OsiamHome.java#L98).  Which is probably not what you want.

A simpler solution is to not use `..` in your html files, either by placing the items under a well-known root directory within the jar and using an absolute reference (e.g. `/libs/jquery-3.1.1.js`), or including the items in the same folder as the html or a subfolder of it (e.g. `jquery-3.1.1.js` or `libs/jquery-3.1.1.js`).

I know this is not the answer you wanted, but I don't have an exact solution to do precisely what you want.

Related question:

- [How to reach css and image files from the html page loaded by javafx.scene.web.WebEngine#loadContent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923801/how-to-reach-css-and-image-files-from-the-html-page-loaded-by-javafx-scene-web-w)