# Why do relative URLs do not work within jar:file protocol (in JavaFX WebView)?

Tags: javafx, webview, jar

I want to use a map in a Java programme and realized that using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) in a JavaFX WebView component. This worked fine until I put the application and the web resources into a jar archive. Then, I could still load the home page, but images, scripts and stylesheets would not be resolved if their locations were specified using relative paths.

Here's a minimal example (the JavaScript code is not necessary, it is only for further inspection):

**webfail/Main.java**

```
package webfail;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            WebView root = new WebView();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            WebEngine webEngine = root.getEngine();
            webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/webfail/home.htm").toExternalForm());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**webfail/home.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Home</h1>
<p>Go to <a href="linked.htm">other page</a>.<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* target of hyperlink */
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  document.writeln("Link href: "+links[0].href+"<br />");
  /* location of website */
  document.writeln("Location href: "+window.location.href+"<br />");
  /* construct a link with an absolute reference */
  lastSlash = window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/");
  document.writeln("Go to <a href=\""+window.location.href.substr(0,lastSlash+1)+"linked.htm\">other page</a>.<br />")
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**webfail/test.js**

```
document.writeln("test.js is loaded.<br />");
```

I left out `webfail/linked.htm`. It could be any html file.

---

Now the webpage that I get as a result looks like this:

> Home
>
> Go to other page.
>   Link href: file:///some/path/bin/webfail/linked.htm
>   Location href: file:///some/path/bin/webfail/home.htm
>   Go to other page.
>   test.js is loaded.

If I click one of the two links, I get to the second page. However, if I export the project into a jar archive, I get the following result:

> Home
>
> Go to other page.
>   Link href: linked.htm
>   Location href: jar:file:/some/other/path/WebFail.jar!/webfail/home.htm
>   Go to other page.

As can be seen, the first hyperlink refers only to linked.htm and nothing happens when it is clicked. Using javascript the second link is pointed to `jar:file:/some/other/path/WebFail.jar!/webfail/linked.htm` and it works just fine.

Why does Java behave in such a way and what is the cause? Is it the WebView component or the handler for jar:file protocol? This behaviour does not seem logical to me, especially since the problem is not loading images/scripts/stylesheets from the jar archive, but the resolution of the relative paths.

I also wonder if that problem does not exist in all Java/JavaFX versions. I use use the `openjdk-8` and `openjfx 8` packages on Ubuntu 16.04.3. In this question, it seems like the author can load a JS script via a relative URL: [JavaFX WebView does not load upper folder script in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933871/javafx-webview-does-not-load-upper-folder-script-in-jar) . It seems that the author of this post [javafx 2 webview custom url handler, don't work relative url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709777/javafx-2-webview-custom-url-handler-dont-work-relative-url) dealt with the same issue and circumvented it by creating his own protocol handler. A better explanation of what to do can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769454/9066947).

At the moment, my best option seems to be to not include my web resources in the jar archive, so that they can be accessed via the `file` protocol.